# Bitnami webserver in localhost doesn't display any errors

Tags: php, bitnami

I know the question has been asked several times but I swear that I tried them all really. I'm using Bitnami to run my application in PHP, but from the start the webserver has never shown error messages, I tried to set in php.ini the following settings:

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting (E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
```

I rebooted the server but nothing has worked.
I've also seen this question:

[How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

one of the answers has had many ups but frankly did not work for me.
I need to fix this annoying because when I load the page of my script I get a blank page and I can not waste my time looking for errors.
First with xampp this did not happen.

Comment: Have you checked the error log? While it's not a solution to the issue here, it will help you finding out why.

Comment: create a file and type something that would cause an error such as test() which doesnt exist and if you see an error then errors are turned on, if you dont then go into php.ini and set display_errors to 1 because sometimes ini_set doesnt work. Also i recommend using vagrant rather than bitnami.

Comment: Ok I've fixed with Sarmen. Instead of display_errors = on I've put display_errors = 1 and now seems working. Thank you.